# Fetch values of primary key rows that were matched by "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"?

Tags: mysql

**Given**:

```sql
INSERT INTO products (product_id, product_name, stocks)
VALUES (1, 'VPN Product 1', 45)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE stocks = VALUES(stocks);
```

**Question**:

How can I combine the INSERT above with a `SELECT id FROM products`  to see which rows were updated as a result of `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

In other words, I need to do **upsert** and retrieve primary keys of rows that caused `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to fire.

Comment: You cannot in mysql. You need a separate select for id to check if it is there already in the table.

Comment: Any way with a stored procedure?

Comment: It does not matter, whether you use a stored proc or not. You need a separate select statement to check for record existence before executing the insert.

Comment: Are you inserting one row at a time or multiple rows in a single statement?

Comment: Multiple rows..